# How to retrieve text from a multiline <tag> through selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get text "1 file has been successfully uploaded." from below code

```
<div class="formbuttons">
<h3 id="res" class="demo" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); display: block;">
<center>1 file <br>has been successfully uploaded.</center>
</h3>
</div>
```

I am using:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id=\"res\"]/center"));
String strng =  element.getText();
System.out.println(strng);
```

but I am not getting any output. what is wrong here?

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: Actually no exception. I want to derive the text for verification but I am not able to get the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the HTML you have provided you can use the following code block to print *1 file has been successfully uploaded.* :

```
String my_string = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='formbuttons']/h3[@class='demo' and @id='res']/center")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
String[] stringParts = my_string.split(Pattern.quote("<br>"));
String partA = stringParts[0];
String partB = stringParts[1];
System.out.println(partA + partB);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `tagname` mentioned in your `xpath`. Try this:

`WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='res']/center"));`

Also, one thing that I came across when using your `HTML` was that some `HTML` formatters told me that it was not a well-formed `HTML`. So if possible, you can do `<br/>` instead of `<br>`. Just a heads-up.

Comment: No, this is not working.  but when i change xpath to By.xpath(".//*[@id='res']/center/text()")  i am getting an error    invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression ".//*[@id='res']/center/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.

Comment: Remove the `/text()` at the end.

Comment: Yes after removing /text()..still same problem no text output : Starting ChromeDriver 2.34.522932 (4140ab217e1ca1bec0c4b4d1b148f3361eb3a03e) on port 6225
Only local connections are allowed.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Feb 10, 2018 12:12:23 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#res > center"));
String text =  element.getAttribute("innerHTML");
System.out.println(text);
```

"innerHTML" worked for me.